# Running R Models using rpy2 interface on Docker. I am facing issue related to opening the port

Tags: python, r, docker, rpy2

- First, I ran R models in windows system using rpy2 python interface. It's running fine.
- Then, I migrate it to linux environment using docker. Now I'm executing same  code with Docker run command, facing "rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeWarning:port 11752 cannot be opened ".

Note: my application running four R models using rpy2. That means it's create four robjects. So I think same time they are using same port. However, I'm not sure.

Help in this issue really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A self-contained example (that is something that anyone interested in answering could copy/paste) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolve this problem myself. This is very python script specific problem. In R command call from python, just need to change TBATS and BATS function. (very specific problem if someone works with R timeseries library)